# Where there are

Tags: relative-clauses, where

I want to have a sentence like this:

In addition, to efficiently calculate f(t) after adding an item x at position p, where there are q relevant items before, we can use Eq. 3.

Is this grammatically correct? What better phrase can I use instead of "where there are q relevant items before"

Comment: Yes, it works. If you are looking for alternatives, you can substitute *if* or *in case* or *given that* for *where.*

Comment: Do there have to be *exactly* **q** such items? I'm guessing probably not. So you could say, perhaps, *To efficiently calculate f(t) after adding an item x at position p, [then] **provided** there are **at least** q **preceding** relevant items, we can use Eq. 3*. I would discard the superfluous *In addition*, since it's contextually obvious you're writing something additional, and the sentence structure is already somewhat "sprawling".

Comment: or "such that there are ..."

Comment: Yes. There are exactly q item.

Comment: @Graffito: My main problem is with before and its usage

Comment: Is it me or would this be significantly improved if short declarative sentences were used instead?

Answer (score 1):

*Where there are* can be *with*.

> In addition, to efficiently calculate f(t) after adding an item x at position p, with q relevant items before, we can use Eq. 3.

However, *q relevant items before* is a bit hard to parse, at least in this context.  Does this work?

> In addition, to efficiently calculate f(t) after adding an item x at position p, with q relevant items in positions prior to p, we can use Eq. 3.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of relevant items Q={q<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>), q<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>2</sub>), q<sub>3</sub>(x<sub>3</sub>),..., q<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>n</sub>)}, Equation 3 will efficiently calculate f(t) when we add q<sub>n+1</sub>(x<sub>n+1</sub>) to Q.

Comment: My favorite, the driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.  If you don't have the common courtesy to voice your opinion on the answer, try to remember that in doing so, you leave no opportunity for the owner to correct a wrong answer and you mislead readers into thinking that correct answers are wrong.